# Determining the last async function called in a forEach in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a async function call `queue.enqueue` in each iteration of `docs.forEach`. How do I determine when is the last iteration of `docs.forEach`?

The following code prints the `console.log` message multiple times instead of on the last `queue.enqueue` call.

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs')
var db = mongojs('localhost/test')
var collection = db.collection('myCollection')

var monq = require('monq')
var client = monq('mongodb://localhost:27017/test')
var queue = client.queue('testQueue')



async.waterfall([

    function(callback) {
        collection.find({}, function(err, docs) {
            callback(null, docs)
        })
    },


    function(docs, callback) {
        docs.forEach(function(doc, index) {

            // Async call here
            queue.enqueue('someTask', doc, function(err, job) {
                // Determining the last iteration of docs.forEach
                if(index = docs.length-1) {
                    console.log('this is the last async call')
                    callback(null)
                }
            }

        })
    }

])
```

Comment: if (index === docs.length - 1)